# Thread implemented as a Singleton

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton

I have a commercial application made with C,C++/Qt on Linux platform. The app collects data from different sensors and displays them on GUI. Each of the protocol for interfacing with sensors is implemented using singleton pattern and threads from Qt QThreads class. All the protocols except one work fine. Each protocol's run function for thread has following structure:

```
void <ProtocolClassName>::run()
{
while(!mStop)  //check whether screen is closed or not
{

mutex.lock()
  while(!waitcondition.wait(&mutex,5))
  {
   if(mStop)
      return;
  }

  //Code for receiving and processing incoming data

 mutex.unlock();
} //end while
}
```

Hierarchy of GUI.

1.Login screen. 
2. Screen of action.

When a user logs in from login screen, we enter the action screen where all data is displayed and all the thread's for different sensors start. They wait on mStop variable in idle time and when data arrives they jump to receiving and processing data. Incoming data for the problem protocol is 117 bytes. In the main GUI threads there are timers which when timeout, grab the running instance of protocol using

```
   <ProtocolName>::instance() function
```

Check the update variable of singleton class if its true and display the data. When the data display is done they reset the update variable in singleton class to false. The problematic protocol has the update time of 1 sec, which is also the frame rate of protocol. When I comment out the display function it runs fine. But when display is activated the application hangs consistently after 6-7 hours. I have asked this question on many forums but haven't received any worthwhile suggestions. I Hope that here I will get some help. Also, I have read a lot of literature on Singleton, multithreading, and found that people always discourage the use of singletons especially in C++. But in my application I can think of no other design for implementation.

Thanks in advance

A Hapless programmer

Comment: you need to clarify: what is implemented in separate threads? where do the threads live? on the GUI? on the sensors? On a central server? who accesses the threads? do the threads live on the same app that accesses them?

Comment: It is a single application. Each sensor has a protocol to interface with it and a frame rate. Thus each protocol is implemented as a singleton thread. The threads start when the user is authenticated and enters action screen. Each protocol thread is a member of the main GUI THREAD class. Based upon the frame rate, we set up an equivalent timer in the GUI thread which when times out GUI THREAD grabs the protocol instance and displays data based upon update variable of protocol class. And after updating the data on GUI resets this variable to false. This update variable is a member of eachprotoc

Answer (score 2):

I think singleton is not really what you are looking for. Consider this:

You have (lets say) two sensors, each with its own protocol (frame rate, for our purpose).

Now create "server" classes for each sensor instead of an explicit singleton. This way you can hide the details of how your sensors work:

```
class SensorServer {
protected:
   int lastValueSensed;
   QThread sensorProtocolThread;
public:
   int getSensedValue() { return lastValueSensed; }
}

class Sensor1Server {
public: 
   Sensor1Server() {
        sensorProtocolThread = new Sensor1ProtocolThread(&lastValueSensed);
        sensorProtocolThread.start();
   }
}

class Sensor1ProtocolThread : public QThread {
protected:
    int* valueToUpdate;
    const int TIMEOUT = 1000; // "framerate" of our sensor1
public:
    Sensor1ProtocolThread( int* vtu ) {
        this->valueToUpdate = vtu;
    }
    void run() {
        int valueFromSensor;
        // get value from the sensor into 'valueFromSensor'
        *valueToUpdate = valueFromSensor;
        sleep(TIMEOUT);
    }
}
```

This way you can do away with having to implement a singleton.

Cheers,

jrh.

Comment: I have to display this value in widget of GUI and since sensor protocol is a member of GUI THREAD CLASS, I have to use protocol class handle to access its members? Also to notify the protocol thread about incoming data I have used global interrupt handler (the only method on Linux I can think of using sigaction and sigio signal handlers) which wakes up the appropriate thread on receiving input on serial port. In this scenario can you suggest something.
But thank you very much for giving me a different perspective to think on. But I m still not clear about how this design would fit my app

Answer (score 0):

Just a drive-by analysis but this doesn't smell right.

If the application is "consistently" hanging after 6-7 hours are you sure it isn't a resource (e.g. memory) leak?  Is there anything different about the implementation of the problematic protocol from the rest of them?  Have you run the app through a memory checker, etc.?

Comment: I haven't mem checked the app but I have observed that memory usage increases steadily. If initially it is 175 MB then after a day's run it increases to 300 MB's. But this is when checked for the whole system using gnome-system-monitor or top cmd. The system isn't used during testing. Also, the core implementation is same as I mentioned above only, the data related implementation is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the cause of what you're seeing, but you have a big fat synchronization bug in your code:

```
void <ProtocolClassName>::run()
{
    while(!mStop)  //check whether screen is closed or not
    {

        mutex.lock()
        while(!waitcondition.wait(&mutex,5))
        {
            if(mStop)
                return; // BUG: missing mutex.unlock()
        }

        //Code for receiving and processing incoming data

        mutex.unlock();
    } //end while
}
```

better:

```
void <ProtocolClassName>::run()
{
    while(!mStop)  //check whether screen is closed or not
    {
        const QMutexLocker locker( &mutex );
        while(!waitcondition.wait(&mutex,5))
        {
            if(mStop)
                return; // OK now
        }

        //Code for receiving and processing incoming data

    } //end while
}
```